# I want to record voice from microphone, but the record button of my vlc is disabled

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, recording

I would like to record sound from microphone on my PC using VLC media player.

I used view->"advanced controls" to make the record button visible.
However, this button is disabled.
How can I enable it to record sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have something playing in VLC for the Record button to be active.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to record some sound from microphone. What should I do?

Comment: As-is, this answer answers your question of "How do I enable the record button in VLC".   Anyhow, if recording from a mic is what you want, then don't use VLC, and instead use a sound recorder (probably one built into your OS).  Please edit your question to include what you ACTUALLY want to do, information like your OS, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the question. And your current answer solves my problem. I am going to use another software. Thanks.